# Non blocking win32com.client.Dispatch

Tags: python, com

I have a python application that creates outlook messages. I call this app externally, however, it blocks after the message is created. Is there a way to disconnect the python app from the COM object after creation? See code below:

```
oOutlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
oItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
oItem.Body = "This is text"
oItem.Display(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just delete the object:

```
del oOutlook
```